# It should be coming up here

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

In the TV show "*The Leftovers*" a family bough a house at an auction. The circumstances surrounding this purchase resulted in them no knowing what the house really looks like or where exactly it is located. They are driving in a car and the femal companion is holding a folder in her hand (presumably with a map inside) and she says to her male companion (who is driving) while looking out the window from the passanger seat:

"*It should be coming up here* (the house) *on the right in just a sec.*"

Does "*come up*" in this context mean something to the tune of "*appear*" like in this definition...

Arise, present itself, as in *This question never came up.*
(The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust)

​...? Or, in it isn't an the idiom "*come up*" but the verb "*come*" which means...

To move into view; appear: *The moon came over the horizon.*

...followed by "*up here*" which means essentailly the same thing as "*here*"?